# Update table based on join among three tables: Help please

Tags: mysql, select, join

I have following 3 tables:

```
storage (
id, 
client, 
cost, -- which have no values
col_1, -- which have no values
col_2, -- which have no values
col_3, -- which have no values
and other columns
)

output(
id, 
client, 
col_1,
col_2,
col_3
)

ad(
id, 
client,
cost,
and other colums
)
```

storage table have 170 rows, output have 50 and ad table has 1000 rows.

What I need is that update storage.cost 
with values from ad.cost, update storage.col_1, storage.col_2, storage.col_3 with values from output.col_1, output.col_2, 
output.col_3 based on join on client column among 3 tables.

If update query isn't possible then I need select query based
on join on client column among 3 tables so that I can insert into another table and use that table instead of storage. 
I need all colums from storage, col_1, col_2, col_3 from output and cost from ad table and 170 rows so that update query isn't 
require and I can use these 170 rows as storage table.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion the database model design is wrong.

Why don't you create a view `v_storage` based on other tables:

```
CREATE VIEW v_storage AS 
    SELECT o.client, a.cost, o.col_1, o.col_2, o.col_3, s.other_columns 
    FROM output AS o 
    JOIN ad AS a ON a.client = o.client 
    JOIN storage AS s ON s.client = o.client
```

And remove the duplicate `cost`, `col_N` columns from the storage table.

**EDITED:**

But if you still need the answer for the question asked, you can specify multiple tables in your `UPDATE` statement and use the tables for selecting in them:

```
UPDATE storage, output, ad
    SET storage.cost = ad.cost, storage.col_1 = output.col_1, ...
WHERE output.client = storage.client
AND ad.client = storage.client
```